# Why is this one line until loop not behaving as expected?

Tags: bash, sh

I have this one line shell script where I am attempting to continuously connect to my Redis server until connection is established (outputs 'OK' on success). However, I must be doing something wrong as the script seemingly does...nothing.

```
bash-5.0# sh -c "until [ $response=="OK" ]; do response="$((printf "AUTH <redis pw>\r\n") | nc -w5 <redis IP> <redis port>)"; echo $response; done;"
bash-5.0#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you first run `set -x` and then try your command, you'll see what's being executed. In this case it's `sh -c 'until [ ==OK ]; do response=; echo ; done;'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't assume that `sh` and `bash` are the same. In most places they are not, and even `bash` will behave differently when invoked as `sh`.

At the moment, your `until` condition always evaluates as `true` because the expression is considered merely a non-null string. To demonstrate:

```
$ [ ==OK ] && echo yo
yo
```

Remember that `[` is an alias for `/bin/test`. You can `man test` for documentation, but the short answer is, use a single equals, and spaces around everything. Oh, and quote the *variables*, not the special-character-free constants.

In addition, mind your quotes. You start a double quoted string before `until`, and then end it before `OK`. If you want to embed double quotes within double quotes, you need to escape them. But it's even better/clearer if you can avoid them.

Perhaps this:

```
# bash -c 'until [[ "$response" = OK ]]; do response="$(printf "AUTH %s\r\n" "$redis_pw" | nc -w5 <redis IP> <redis port> )"; echo "$response"; done'
```

Or if you prefer to be POSIXy and not depend on bash:

```
# sh -c 'until [ "$response" = OK ]; do response="$(printf "AUTH %s\r\n" "$redis_pw" | nc -w5 <redis IP> <redis port>)"; echo "$response"; done'
```

Comment: `sh: OK: unknown operand`

Comment: @bbmhmmad, Doh, you had single quotes inside single quotes, and I replicated that problem. I believe I've fixed them now. Please try again.

Comment: yup that was it. accepted as answer. thanks a lot. need to learn more about shell scripting for sure